# How do I delete a file with a NULL byte in the filename?

Tags: filesystem, macos

I made a file by accident with a filename of `(NUL).xml`, except instead of `(NUL)`, it's literally `'\0'`. None of the methods I've tried have worked to actually delete it. Is there a way I can delete the file by an alternative reference?

Comment: I created it with an old version of Java that let me create files with a null byte in the file name by accident. Unfortunately, I've long since updated and clri isn't available on El Capitan, so I can't even clear the inode.

Comment: I've tried that and many more. It doesn't work.

Comment: I'm more or less hoping someone has a method for clearing inodes on El Capitan.

Comment: The problem with that is that it attempts to delete the file using the file's name, which is exactly the problem. The null byte is tripping up rm.

Comment: Yeah. That runs into the same problem as its invoking the unlink() call against the file name.

Comment: Tried it with `clri /dev/disk0s2 -inode` (from a 10.6 install copied to a 10.9 system) and directly manipulating the catalog file with a hex editor. Nothing works or completely corrupts the disk (the latter).

Comment: By "completely corrupts the disk", do you mean requires fsck? Because that is known and expected behavior with clri.

Comment: clri just doesn't work with the following (error?) message: `clri: /dev/disk0s2: superblock magic number 0x0, not 0x11954`. Directly manipulating the file system's catalog file with a hex editor completely corrupts the volume and it can't be recovered though I changed only 4 bytes.

Comment: Is it the only file in a directory? Or is it the only file with a certain extension? Than you could try using ```rm``` with a wildcard instead of the offending character or remove the whole directory (```rm -rf ./THEDIRECTORY```)? Or you could look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28983/how-can-i-delete-a-file-with-no-name which might also help. I usually search for linux answers in these cases. Other solution: install midnight commander - that usually works in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I cannot test this (for hopefully obvious reasons), but when filenames are your issue... use `inode`s!

First, in a directory, run `ls -il` (-i is *show node numbers* and -l is to make it a list):

```
2480878 -rw-r--r--  1 christopher  family  0 Mar  2 19:40 *a
2480889 -rw-r--r--  1 christopher  family  0 Mar  2 19:40 \\a
2480873 -rw-r--r--  1 christopher  family  0 Mar  2 19:39 a
```

In this example, I'm going to erase the file `\\a`, which is inode `2480889`.

So I run `find . -inum 2480889 -delete`.

Hopefully this will work.

Comment: `find . -inum 43396691 -delete` produces `find: -delete: unlink(./␀.xml): Invalid argument`

Comment: :( darn! That sucks!